# Monodevelop throws the following exception System.DllNotFoundException: SDL2.dll

Tags: c#, sdl, monodevelop, monogame

To be more precise, here is the error I get when I try to run an application built using monogame:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: SDL2.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) SDL2.SDL:SDL_SetMainReady ()
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.SDL2_GameWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.SDL2_GamePlatform..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.Create (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MovingTeddyBears.Game1..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MovingTeddyBears.Program.Main () [0x00000] in /home/Dan/Desktop/MonoDevelopPrograms/LinuxMonoGameMovingTeddyBears/Program.cs:19
```

There are no errors on compiling the program, but when I run it, I get the above output.
I am on linux mint running monodevelop 3.0.3

```bsh
ldconfig -p | grep libSDL2
    libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0
    libSDL2-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
```

Any help is welcome please help me resolve this.

Comment: Which Version of Linux Mind are you using? This https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Tutorials:Getting-Started-Guide-Linux says you need version 13, does not specify if 32 or 64 bit though. Either way just a starting point and hope the link helps in case you haven't come across it yet.

Comment: Using linux mint 15 Olivia. I've taken a look at that same tutorial and another one offered on the site and that did not solve the problem. Problem was solved when I downloaded monogame [here](http://monogame.codeplex.com/releases/view/102870). Then I installed it as an addin to monodevelop using the monodevelop addin manager. Now the problem is solved, but thanks for atleast a comment

Comment: No Problem, glad you got it working.